# Space Complexity of this quicksort implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

This question is general, but also has a function in question:

```py
def quick_sort(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2: return lst
    pivot_lst = lst[0]
    left_side = [el for el in lst[1:] if el < pivot_lst]
    right_side = [el for el in lst[1:] if el >= pivot_lst]
    return quick_sort(left_side) + [pivot_lst] + quick_sort(right_side)
```

Time complexity: `O(nlog(n))` expected, `O(n^2)` worst case

Space complexity: ???

So for the expected time complexity, which the best case of would be when `left` and `right` are split evenly the following series would apply for n size input:

```
n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 +...  +1 
= n(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + ... . )
= O(n)
```

It follows that in the worst case, which occurs when the pivot point selected is the largest or smallest value in the list, this would apply:

```
n + (n-1) + (n-2) +... + 1
= (n^2 + n) / 2 
= O(n^2)
```

My question is, do the series' above represent expected and worst space complexities of `O(n)` and `O(n^2)`, respectively?

I'm struggling with the idea of how stack frame memory comes into play here.
Would we just add it on?

So, if its `O(log(n))`, then space complexity is `O(n) + O(log(n)) -> O(n)`

Or would its relationship with the auxiliary data be something else?

Can I conclude that when both an auxiliary data structure and recursive stack are present, we only need to calculate the larger of the two?

Answer (score 1):

## Summary

In this implementation of Quicksort, yes—the expected [auxiliary](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/108512/46033) space complexity is `O(n)` and the worst-case auxiliary space complexity is `O(n^2)`.

> I'm struggling with the idea of how stack frame memory comes into play here. Would we just add it on?
>
> So, if its O(log(n)), then space complexity is O(n) + O(log(n)) -> O(n)
>
> [...]
>
> Can I conclude that when both an auxiliary data structure and recursive stack are present, we only need to calculate the larger of the two?

No.

I think you're correctly noticing that the recursive stack *depth* is `O(log(n))` in the expected case, but incorrectly thinking that that means its *space complexity* is also `O(log(n))` in the expected case. That's not necessarily true.

- An individual stack frame can represent more space than `O(1)`.
- How much space a frame represents might *vary from frame to frame.*

So, when finding an algorithm's total space complexity, you can't analyze its recursion depth separately from its data requirements, and then add the two up at the end. You need to analyze them together.

In general, you'll need to understand:

- How deep the recursion goes—how many stack frames there will be.
- For each of those stack frames, what its space complexity is. This includes function arguments, local variables, and so on.

Then, you can add up the space complexities of all the stack frames that will be simultaneously active.

## Example: Expected case

Imagine this function call tree for `n=8`. I'm using the notation `quick_sort(n)` to mean "quicksort with a list of `n` elements."

```
quick_sort(8)
    quick_sort(4)
        quick_sort(2)
            quick_sort(1)
            quick_sort(1)
        quick_sort(2)
            quick_sort(1)
            quick_sort(1)
    quick_sort(4)
        quick_sort(2)
            quick_sort(1)
            quick_sort(1)
        quick_sort(2)
            quick_sort(1)
            quick_sort(1)
```

Since your implementation is single-threaded, only one branch will be active at a time. At its deepest, that will look like:

```
quick_sort(8)
    quick_sort(4)
        quick_sort(2)
            quick_sort(1)
```

Or, in general:

```
quick_sort(n)
    quick_sort(n/2)
        quick_sort(n/4)
            ...
                quick_sort(1)
```

Let's look at the space that each frame will consume.

```
<calling function>
    lst: O(n)
    
    quick_sort(n)
        lst: O(1)
        pivot_lst: O(1)
        left_side: O(n/2)
        right_side: O(n/2)
        
        quick_sort(n/2)
            lst: O(1)
            pivot_lst: O(1)
            left_side: O(n/4)
            right_side: O(n/4)
            
            quick_sort(n/4)
                lst: O(1)
                pivot_lst: O(1)
                left_side: O(n/8)
                right_side: O(n/8)
                
                ...
                    quick_sort(1)
                        lst: O(1)
```

Note that I'm considering the `lst` argument to always have a space complexity of `O(1)` to reflect Python lists being pass-by-reference. If we made it `O(n)`, `O(n/2)`, etc., we would be double-counting it, because it's really the same object as the calling function's `left_side` or `right_side`. This won't end up mattering for the final result of this particular algorithm, but you'll need to keep it in mind, in general.

I'm also being notationally sloppy. Writing `O(n/2)` makes it tempting to immediately simplify it to `O(n)`. Don't do that yet: if you do, you'll end up overstating the total space complexity.

Simplifying a bit:

```
<calling function>
    lst: O(n)

    quick_sort(n)
        everything: O(n/2)

        quick_sort(n/2)
            everything: O(n/4)

            quick_sort(n/4)
                everything: O(n/8)

                ...
                    quick_sort(1)
                        everything: O(1)
```

Adding them up:

```
O(n) + O(n/2) + O(n/4) + O(n/8) + ... + O(1)
= O(n)
```

## Example: Worst case

Using the same methodology as above, but skipping some steps for brevity:

```
<calling function>
    lst: O(n)

    quick_sort(n)
        everything: O(n-1)

        quick_sort(n-1)
            everything: O(n-2)

            quick_sort(n-2)
                everything: O(n-3)

                ...
                    quick_sort(1)
                        everything: O(1)
```

```
O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + O(n-3) + ... + O(1)
= O(n^2)
```

Comment: Thanks for going so in depth. 1st line - "space complexities are respectively O(n) and O(n^2), the same as the expected and worst-case time complexities.". If you re-read my question, my expected time complexities are O(nlog(n)) and O(n^2). I felt pretty confident about that - is it wrong or you miswrote?

Comment: "I think you're correctly noticing that the recursive stack depth is O(log(n)), but incorrectly thinking that that means its space complexity is also O(log(n))." - lost me here. Why do we add left_side and right_side to every frame when like you said only one branch will be active at a time. Wouldn't one of them just be O(1) in that case, just like lst - hence O(log(n)) total and not O(n). And how is what you're doing above not adding O(n) + O(log(n)) = O(n) (aka auxiliary data + recursion depth)

Comment: Good questions. I'll try to clarify these points soon; I might need to remind myself of what I wrote. :P

Comment: @devdev_dev I think the first line was just a silly mistake on my part. I've edited this answer to fix it. Your time complexities of `O(nlog(n))` and `O(n^2)` seem correct (but I haven't tried to replicate that analysis myself).

Comment: @devdev_dev To try to get us on the same page for your remaining questions, could you clarify where you got the terms `O(n)` and `O(log(n))` when you said: "So, if its `O(log(n))`, then space complexity is `O(n) + O(log(n)) -> O(n)`"? And what is "it" in that context?